# rule based questioning answering for reading comprehension (QUARC)

Tags: asp-classic, nlp

Does anyone know  the algorithm and asp classic script about rule based questioning answering for reading comprehension (QUARC) for WHAT, WHY, and HOW ? I need to integrate it with the database. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The [original paper about Quarc](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/W/W00/W00-0603.pdf) (CiteseerX page [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.21.1076)) gives heuristics for WHO, WHAT, WHEN, WHERE and WHY, but not HOW (the authors mention in a footnote that "There is also a lone HOW question in the data set, but we ignored it.").

Comment: thanks for your reply, now I confuse about how to begin to create the application. is there any idea?

Comment: That's probably best asked in another question once you've had a go at it yourself. Also, if you liked this reply, please vote it up! :)